# Criteria in Process Builder

Tags: criteria

In the Process Builder I’m trying to set a Criteria entered in a record being a future date in a calendar.  Equals>Type is no good because I have to enter a date.  Should I select:  Field-Date Calendar>  Operation - Equals>  Type-Reference>  Value-Calendar Field or do I need to create a formula?

Comment: Tim, it will help the users to answer if you can provide a bit more detail and may be a screen shot as well. thanks.